# Given $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with two real roots, $x_1>x_2$, find a quadratic equation whose roots are $x_1+1$ and $x_2-1$ without solving the first equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

Roots of the equation $ (1): ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. They are both real.

Without solving first equation, make up new quadratic equation such that one of the its roots is $x_{1} + 1$ and second one is $x_{2}-1$. Note that $x_{2}>x_{1}$.

I started to solve this with Vieta's theorem but I couldn't continue. Deep explanation would be grateful!

Also I don't know what does not solve mean, I can't use a quadratic formula or something more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ is given to you. Consider
\begin{align*}
g(x)&=a(x-(x_1+1))(x-(x_2-1))\\
&=a(x-x_1-1)(x-x_2+1)\\
&=a(\color{red}{(x-x_1)}-1)(\color{blue}{(x-x_2)}+1)\\
&=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+a(x-x_1)-a(x-x_2)-a\\
&=f(x)+a\underbrace{(x_2-x_1)}_{\text{given }>0}-a.
\end{align*}
Now $x_2-x_2=\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)-\frac{4c}{a}}=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$
Thus
$$g(x)=ax^2+bx+c+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}-a$$

Comment: How did you transform second line into third?

Comment: @NikaChelidze I have added a step to highlight multiplication of appropriate terms. Does that help?

Comment: Yes a lot! Thank you

Comment: The factorization of $ax^2 + bx + c$ is $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$, isn't it? There seems to be an $a$ missing.

Answer (score 2):

Since, $x_1 $ & $x_2$ are the roots of the quadratic equation: $ax^2+bx+c=0$, hence we have
$$\text{sum of roots,} \ x_1+x_2=-\frac ba, \ \ \text{product of roots,}\ x_1x_2=\frac ca$$
Now, the equation having roots: $x_1+1 $ & $x_2-1$ is given as $$(x-(x_1+1))(x-(x_2-1))=0$$
$$x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2-1-(\underbrace{x_2-x_1}_{>0})=0$$
$$x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2-1-\sqrt{(x_2+x_1)^2-4x_1x_2}=0$$
setting the values, we get
$$x^2-\left(-\frac ba\right)x+\frac ca-1-\sqrt{\left(-\frac ba\right)^2-4\frac ca}=0$$

$$\color{blue}{ax^2+bx+c-a+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0}$$
Above is the required quadratic equation.

Comment: I thought to solve problem with this way but i thought it would be against the problem because it says don't solve the equation. What do you think?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: I edited my answer. What do you think now?